# How to find elements common in at least 2 vectors?

Tags: r, vector, set-operations

Say I have 5 vectors:

```
a <- c(1,2,3)
b <- c(2,3,4)
c <- c(1,2,5,8)
d <- c(2,3,4,6)
e <- c(2,7,8,9)
```

I know I can calculate the intersection between all of them by using `Reduce()` together with `intersect()`, like this:

```
Reduce(intersect, list(a, b, c, d, e))
[1] 2
```

But how can I find elements that are common in, say, at least 2 vectors? i.e.:

```
[1] 1 2 3 4 8
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is much simpler than a lot of people are making it look. This should be very efficient.

1. Put everything into a vector:

   ```
   x <- unlist(list(a, b, c, d, e))
   ```
2. Look for duplicates

   ```
   unique(x[duplicated(x)])
   # [1] 2 3 1 4 8
   ```

and `sort` if needed.

Note: In case there can be duplicates within a list element (which your example does not seem to implicate), then replace `x` with `x <- unlist(lapply(list(a, b, c, d, e), unique))`

---

Edit: as the OP has expressed interest in a more general solution where n >= 2, I would do:

```
which(tabulate(x) >= n)
```

if the data is only made of natural integers (1, 2, etc.) as in the example. If not:

```
f <- table(x)
names(f)[f >= n]
```

This is now not too far from James solution but it avoids the costly-ish `sort`. And it is miles faster than computing all possible combinations.

Comment: Nice one. Can this be generalised for n > 2? As in, how do I find elements common in at least n vectors?

Comment: No, it would require I use a frequency table via `table` or `tabulate`, see my edit.

Answer (score 2):

You could try all possible combinations, for example:

```
## create a list
l <- list(a, b, c, d)

## get combinations
cbn <- combn(1:length(l), 2)

## Intersect them 
unique(unlist(apply(cbn, 2, function(x) intersect(l[[x[1]]], l[[x[2]]]))))
## 2 3 1 4
```

Comment: Can you please explain what is the first argument to combn() (1:4)?

Comment: I changed it to `length(l)` which is more generic. It creates all possible combination of n elements when you choose k.

Answer (score 2):

Here's another option:

```
# For each vector, get a vector of values without duplicates
deduplicated_vectors <- lapply(list(a,b,c,d,e), unique)

# Flatten the lists, then sort and use rle to determine how many
# lists each value appears in
rl <- rle(sort(unlist(deduplicated_vectors)))

# Get the values that appear in two or more lists
rl$values[rl$lengths >= 2]
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an approach that counts the number of vectors each unique value occurs in.

```
unique_vals <- unique(c(a, b, c, d, e))

setNames(rowSums(!!(sapply(list(a, b, c, d, e), match, x = unique_vals)),
                 na.rm = TRUE), unique_vals)
# 1 2 3 4 5 8 6 7 9 
# 2 5 3 2 1 2 1 1 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Yet another approach, applying a vectorised function with `outer`:

```
L <- list(a, b, c, d, e)
f <- function(x, y) intersect(x, y)
fv <- Vectorize(f, list("x","y"))
o <- outer(L, L, fv)
table(unlist(o[upper.tri(o)]))

#  1  2  3  4  8 
#  1 10  3  1  1
```

The output above gives the number of pairs of vectors that share each of the duplicated elements 1, 2, 3, 4, and 8.

Answer (score 0):

A variation of @rengis method would be:

```
unique(unlist(Map(`intersect`, cbn[1,], cbn[2,])))
#[1] 2 3 1 4 8
```

where,

```
l <- mget(letters[1:5])
cbn <- combn(l,2)
```

Answer (score 0):

When the vector is huge, solutions like `duplicated` or `tabulate` might overflow your system. In that case, dplyr comes in handy with the following code

```
library(dplyr) combination_of_vectors <- c(a, b, c, d, e)
#For more than 1 
combination_of_vectors %>% as_tibble() %>% group_by(x) %>% filter(n()>1)
#For more than 2 
combination_of_vectors %>% as_tibble() %>% group_by(x) %>% filter(n()>2)
#For more than 3 
combination_of_vectors %>% as_tibble() %>% group_by(x) %>% filter(n()>2)
```

Hope it helps somebody