# R find matches for more than 2 vectors

Tags: r, excel, matching, grepl

I am working with a set of 5 excel columns `A,B,C,D,E` of words `"Aaa","Aab"...` and I want to find the exact matches in all the columns (in R).

```
A   B   C   D   E  
Aaa Aaa Baa Aaa Ass
Aab Ccc Aaa Baa Aaa
Ccc Abc Ccc Ccc Ccc
... ... ... ... ...
```

I create a vector for each column.
For that I have try a `for` loop with `if` and `grep` function.

```
<pre>
    for(i in A_vector) {
          if(grep("i", B_vector))
              if(grep("i", C_vector))
                  if(grep("i", D_vector))
                      if(grep("i", E_vector))
                          print(i)
      }
<code>
```

(but I only obtain the words in the first vector `A_vector`).
At the end I would like to have a vector with the words `"Aaa", "Bbb"...` that match in the 5 columns. I do not need the position of each match within the vector, just the words that are common to all the vectors.

```
 Result
    [1] "Aaa"
    [2] "Ccc"
    [n]  ...
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Hiho J L Carballo, wellcome to stackoverflow. I think you can archive this with some straight forward comparision. index = which(data$A == data$B & data$A == data$C % data$A == data$D $ data$A == data$E). This gives you the index for every row containing the same string in all colums. So with data[index] you get all the rows with same strings. With data$A[index] you get a vector with all the strings beeing equal over all colums.

Comment: `grep` is excellent for matching patterns with regular expressions. For exact matches use `==` or `%in%`, depending on whether you need element-wise matching or not. However, for finding "elements in common" `intersect` is probably an even better bet. If your input is a data frame named `dd`, I think you're looking for `Reduce(inntersect, dd)`

Comment: Suggested duplicate: [find elements in common for at least 2 vectors](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26175561/903061)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are asking to find common elements between each list, not just duplicates in general. Duplicates below are `Aaa, Ccc, Ddd, and Xxx`, but the only element duplicated across any is `Xxx`. `intersect()` will accomplish this, with some double `lapply` functions.

```
A = list("Aaa", "Aaa", "Ccc", "Ccc")
B = list("Ddd", "Ddd", "Ddd", "Eee")
C = list("Fff", "Ggg", "Hhh", "Iii", "Jjj")
D = list("Kkk", "Lll", "Mmm", "Nnn", "Xxx")
E = list("Ppp", "Qqq", "Rrr", "Xxx")
Mylist <- list(A, B, C, D, E)

dupes <- unlist(lapply(Mylist, function(x) lapply(Mylist, function(y) intersect(x,y))))

unique(dupes[duplicated(dupes)])

[1] "Xxx"
```

To see where the intersections are, this will tell you that your 4th list has 1 element in common with your 5th list:

```
sapply(seq_len(length(Mylist)), function(x) sapply(seq_len(length(Mylist)), function(y) length(intersect(unlist(Mylist[x]), unlist(Mylist[y])))))

     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]    2    0    0    0    0
[2,]    0    2    0    0    0
[3,]    0    0    5    0    0
[4,]    0    0    0    5    1
[5,]    0    0    0    1    4
```

Answer (score -1):

You could try something, though a little convoluted, using data.table:

```
library(data.table)

setDT(data)

data[, unlist(lapply(.SD, intersect, y = unique(A))), A][, .N, A][N == {ncol(dt) - 1}, A]
```

Comment: I'm not sure this accomplishes what OP is looking for.

Answer (score -1):

Here is the edited answer based on your explanation that you want to find all the matches between at least two of the columns:

```
 Mylist <-list(A=c("Aaa","Aab","Ccc","Ddd"), B=c("Aaa","Ccc","Abc","Abd"), C=c("Baa","Aaa","Ccc","Abb","Ddd"), D=c("Aaa","Baa","Ccc","CBB","Baa"),E=c("Ass","Aaa","Ccc","Gef"))
 CharVec <-unlist(Mylist)
 unique(CharVec[duplicated(CharVec)])
```

Comment: I´m working with 5 variables, each one with a length of 150 to 650 words. The words are not repeated within the same variable.
Using either `Reduce(intersect, dd)` or `Reduce(df, intersect)` I obtain an error "argument "init" is missing, with no default". Then I also try calling the `.init` as the first variable but without success.

Comment: Commands and functions are case-specific. You are trying `Reduce` instead of `reduce`. You'll also need `library(purrr)`. @shirin this finds matches between all columns. OP is looking for matches between at least 2 columns.

Comment: @JLCarballo I edited my answer after your comment, please take a look and see if that's what you need

Comment: Thank you @shirin ! It work well this way I obtain all the matches. I also checked with excel and there is no match for all the columns but some between two or 3.

Comment: @JLCarballo this does not do what you are looking for. This ungroups all columns and finds any duplicates. For example `Mylist <-list(A=c("Aaa","Aaa","Ccc","Ccc"), B=c("Ddd","Ddd","Ddd","Eee"), C=c("Fff","Ggg","Hhh","Iii","Jjj"))`, this solution would return `Aaa, Ccc, and Ddd`, which are not duplicated across columns.